# How to update submodules

Tags: git, jenkins

How do I update submodules when on a detached head?

I try

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

but I get the error:

```
You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which
branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>
```

What can I do? Is there another way to update submodules when on a detached head? The use case is that jenkins tries to update submodules on a detached head.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It is perfectly fine for a submodule to be in detached-head mode. As long as it points to the correct commit for the submodule, it should not be a problem for Jenkins.

Why are you using `recursive`? Do the submodules have submodules of their own?

If what you want is for Jenkins to checkout the correct commit for all repositories (the main repository and its submodules) then a simple `git submodule update` should do the trick. BTW, Jenkins knows how to do this for you, there's no reason for you to type that command on your own or anything.

If you want Jenkins to actually *change* the commit at which the submodules are recorded in the main repository, so that they point to the tip of some branch, then it's a very odd thing to do in Jenkins... Typically you don't make code changes in Jenkins.